# Evaluate variable assignment

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am aware of Python's ternary operator:

```
result = a if b else c
```

But what if a and b are the same thing? Let me exemplify it:

```
tasks = ["foo", "bar"]
def tasksLeft():
    return tasks

tasks.remove('foo')
my_tasks = tasksLeft() if tasksLeft() else 'no tasks left'
```

In a first attempt, tasksLeft() would evaluate to True, so the ternary operator would evaluate to `["bar",]`.

```
tasks.remove('bar')
my_tasks = tasksLeft() if tasksLeft() else 'no tasks left'
```

In a second attempt, tasksLeft() would evaluate to False (`[]`), so it would evaluate to the default string.

My hypothetical code would be:

```
if not my_tasks = tasksLeft():
    my_tasks = 'no tasks left'
```

The point is that the value just assigned is evaluated, and if it is False, then assign a different value.

Obviously this is just an example I've just came up with, and I know it is not syntactically correct, but is there a less-repetitive way of writing it?

Comment: `my_tasks = tasksLeft() or 'no tasks left'`

Comment: ahh, you are right, that I didn't think @vaultah. Thank you!

Comment: You can post it as an answer.

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python the logical operators return one of their operands (the first one that can be used to determine the result of the overall expression), so you can use the `or` operator:

```
my_tasks = tasksLeft() or 'no tasks left'
```